# SQL Get First Value From Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I'm running MS SQL-Server-2016 I'm trying to get the first value from a table partitioned an ParentId.  I have a data set like so:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable
(
    PTORequestDetailId INT,
    PTORequestId INT,
    DivisionPTOAccrualId INT,
    RequestDate DATE,
    StartTime DateTime,
    Hours Decimal(19,2),
    ResponseNotes nvarchar(500),
    Status int,
    CreatedOn DateTime,
    ModifiedOn DateTime
)

INSERT INTO #TempTable
SELECT 60,  48, 139, '2015-09-09',  '2015-09-08 20:00:00.000',  8.00,'',0, '2015-09-09 13:30:40.363',   '2015-09-09 13:30:40.313' UNION
SELECT 61,  48, 139, '2015-09-10',  '2015-09-09 20:00:00.000',  8.00,'',0, '2015-09-09 13:30:40.363',   '2015-09-09 13:30:40.313' UNION
SELECT 62,  48, 139, '2015-09-11',  '2015-09-10 20:00:00.000',  8.00,'',0, '2015-09-09 13:30:40.363',   '2015-09-09 13:30:40.313' UNION
SELECT 63,  48, 139, '2015-09-13',  '2015-09-12 20:00:00.000',  8.00,'',0, '2015-09-09 13:30:40.363',   '2015-09-09 13:30:40.313' UNION

CREATE TABLE #TempParent
(
    PTORequestId INT,
)

INSERT INTO #TempParent
SELECT 48
```

Running this will create a temp table with the data set I'm working with.
I'm trying to get out the First Value for the DivisionPTOAccrualId partitioned by the #TempTable.PTORequestId,

```
SELECT #TempParent.*, AccrualDetails.*
FROM #TempParent
CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT FIRST_VALUE(#TempTable.DivisionPTOAccrualId) 
            OVER (PARTITION BY #TempTable.PTORequestId 
                    ORDER BY #TempTable.PTORequestDetailId ASC
                    ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                    ) as AccrualId
        FROM #TempTable
        WHERE #TempTable.PTORequestId = #TempParent.PTORequestId
        ) as AccrualDetails
```

I'm basically Trying to get `139` once per row from my Parent, but the FIRST_VALUE seems to return multiple results so it creating the Cartesian Product.

So instead of Getting a single row result set

PTORequestId: 48
AccrualId:  139

First Value should only return a single Value
Yet its returning 4 values.
Why is this occurring, How can I make FIRST_VALUE return a single value per row?

**EDIT**

I think this is occuring because I'm selecting the FIRST_VALUE from the TempTable, so It's selecting the First Value for Each Row in the Temp Table. But I actually only to do it once

For anyone who needs clarification on what I was doing wrong.
I was expecting my Partition By To Filter Rows in my Table.
I assumed since SUM on a Table will Return the sum of the entire table instead of the SUM of the Entire Table Per Row.  That sum work work based off of the partitioned data which is not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about doing it with `First_Value()`, but I find this easier to do with `Row_Number()` and only taking the first record:

```
;With Cte As
(
    Select  T.*,
            Row_Number() Over (Partition By T.PTORequestId Order By T.PTORequestDetailId) As RN
    From    #TempTable  T
    Join    #TempParent P   On  P.PTORequestId = T.PTORequestId
)
Select  PTORequestId, DivisionPTOAccrualId As AccruralId
From    Cte
Where   RN = 1
```

Comment: First value function essentially does the same thing.   First value is not working because Of how I selected everything.  My join creates multiple rows.

Comment: But this helped me recoginize my issue, I need to do some more research before I can accept this answer, but I think your right I need to use the row number